# Database connection timeout in google cloud sql instance while using task queue handler

Tags: php, laravel, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-tasks

What I am doing?
I am working on google cloud task queue handler. Queues pushed successfully. Google cloud executed these queue internally. I have created app.yaml file where I have written below lines:-

```
handlers:
  - url: /click_queue
    script : click_queue_result.php
```

Now I opened command line and run this command "gcloud app deploy". Then my project is deployed on google cloud server. Now I try to make a DB connection but continuously showing error db connection timeout.

I want to access Google cloud Sql Instance in click_queue_result.php

Please give me suggestion how I can resolve it??

```
<?php
$servername = "IP_ADDRESS";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

When I hit this url https://google-cloud-project-id.appspot.com/click_queue then following error is occurred:-

```
Connection failed: Connection timed out
```

Comment: Hello ! Could it be a missing firewall rule allowing your cloud sql instance to be reached ?

Comment: No, there is firewall rule allowing.

Answer (score 2):

As described in the [Connecting from App Engine documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine) and in the [GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples github page](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/php72/cloudsql), to use Cloud SQL on App Engine for PHP you must either use the provided Unix domain socket or a TCP connection (in the case of an App Engine Flex).

In your case, you won’t be able to connect with the instance’s IP address, instead you need to set its connection name as an environment variable in the app.yaml file. You may refer to the [index.php](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/blob/master/appengine/php72/cloudsql/index.php) file in the github repository for an example using PDO.

---

Comment: I am glad to know that it solved the issue for you. Could you please accept the answer? Just so it gets more visibility for the other users that might have the same issue.